# Injective hull over different rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

Question: Does the injective hull of a module also depend on the ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a local Gorenstein ring which is not regular. Let $M$ be the residue field of $R$. Since $M$ is a field, it is self injective as an $M$-module. However, $M$ is not $R$-injective. Therefore, $E_M(M) = M \neq E_R(M).$

If $M$ were $R$-injective, then it has a finite injective dimension. But since $R$ is Gorenstein, $M$ has a finite projective dimension. This is only possible when $R$ is regular.